# How to have gutentags build tags from the .git folder in a repository?

Tags: tags, ctags

I want to have my tags file generated from gutentags/ctags to be in the .git folder, because I am working on a project with other people where I don't want to edit the .gitignore file. So, I have these 2 lines in my vimrc

```
10 set tags^=.git/tags;
11 let g:gutentags_ctags_tagfile = '.git/tags'
```

However, the problem with this is that all the paths from this are still generated with respect to my root folder, so when vim tries to look for the tag it will throw the error `.git/root/folder/path/file.js does not exist`. Somehow I need to be able to have gutentags generate this tag file with respect to my .git directory.

Comment: Not exactly what you want... But you can create a local gitignore file in `.git/info/exclude` so you don't need to add it to everyone's `.gitignore`. See [gitignore's docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for that.

Comment: Does adding the following to your vimrc fix it? `g:gutentags_ctags_extra_args = ['--tag-relative=no']`